# Default radix accepted issue

Tags: assembly

What is the default radix accepted by the assembly language program editor and 32-bit debug program if an integer constant 26 is keyed in? Does assembly language program editor is the one at the command prompt?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please, edit it and provide some details of what you are asking.

Comment: The default radix in assemblers is usually 10. Though for the `DEBUG` tool in DOS it might be 16. Should be easy enough to find out if you enter a hex value without any prefix or suffix.